# How do I do "char *bufferData = new char[charSize];"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need variable charSize.  How do I do this in objective-c:

```
char *bufferData = new char[charSize]; //c++ notation
```

thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use `malloc`:

```
char *bufferData = malloc(charSize * sizeof(char));
```

(Technically the `sizeof(char)` isn't necessary since chars are always of size 1, but I like to include it anyway so that it looks "wrong" if I accidentally do a malloc without a size.)

But depending on what you're doing, you might want to look into [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) or [NSData](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html), the Cocoa classes for dealing with text and binary data, respectively. The rest of the Cocoa framework generally uses those.

Comment: NSString or NSData, and more likely the mutable variations thereof. (I know you know this, Chuck, this is just for prosterity and the original poster.)

Answer (score 1):

```
char *bufferData = malloc(charSize);
```

I suppose?

Comment: Don't cast the result of malloc though!

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Okay, taken out. I remember it was either "always cast it" or "never cast it" ;)

Comment: It's "always cast it" in C++ and "casting it can only ever hide a mistake" in C.